# All uses of LaTeX (I never use LaTeX except for ...)

Tags: fun, latex-misc, big-list

I am designing a comical T-shirt about LaTeX and I would like it to boast about all the purposes that one can use LaTeX for. I started with

> I **never** use LaTEX *except* for typesetting documents.

and then remembered that you could also make (Beamer) presentations, draw figures, and, well, make T-shirt designs. : ) So I am aiming to add a footnote explaining what all could be understood by "(typesetting) documents". E.g.:

> (Documents, presentations, letters, figures, logos, T-shirt designs, ... you name it!)

So my question is the following: Could you provide a list of all purposes of LaTeX known to (or used by) you - possibly accompanied by the most important package dependencies (e.g. `tikz` for drawing figures).

**PS:** Any suggestions on how to improve the originally proposed T-shirt text may be left in the comments. I shall then post the final design.

**EDIT:** Admitedly, my question is similar to "[What is the most bizarre thing you have seen done with TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104248/what-is-the-most-bizarre-thing-you-have-seen-done-with-tex)", although it concerns TeX while I refer to LaTeX (I am not sure if this matters). Other possible duplicate list is "[In what ways can TeX be used beyond document production?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53082/in-what-ways-can-tex-be-used-beyond-document-production)". I hope that the added value of my question is getting the package dependencies and in the end producing a T-shirt design.

Comment: Ducks and Donkeys https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312199/i-need-a-tex-donkey

Comment: There are the donkeys, here are the ducks: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346695/101651

Comment: I once typeset the board for a “Game of the goose” for my then five-year-old niece.

Comment: Other, more serious examples that I recollected meanwhile: business cards and a double=entry ledger (I wrote a package for the latter).

Comment: On the back -- one of the ducks saying "and me"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most bizarre thing you have seen done with TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104248/what-is-the-most-bizarre-thing-you-have-seen-done-with-tex)

Comment: These are extensively listed here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104248/what-is-the-most-bizarre-thing-you-have-seen-done-with-tex including the weirdest mars rover thing.

Comment: Related to / possible duplicate of [In what ways can TeX be used beyond document production?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53082/69818).

Comment: There was a question here about drawing aeroplanes.

Comment: Part of KOMA-script is a package to create those small booklets for worships.

Comment: Perhaps you could put the source for the t-shirt design on the back.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Nice suggestion. Although I was aiming for the effect of having just "I never use LaTeX" on the front side and the rest on the back side.

Comment: HTML creation based on LaTeX.

Comment: ... cats, cauldrons, Halloween maths, Christmas trees, Thanksgiving, fireworks, Mothers' Day, obscurely-illustrated timelines, people seeds, demons and devils, thought experiments, schemata, extraterrestrials, dilemmas and trilemmas, Turing machines, mind maps, good and evil, trolleology, caves, (good) wills ....

Comment: ... leaflets, pamphlets, course booklets, treasure hunts, certificates, graph paper, framed paper, Sudoku, chess boards, family trees, all kinds of trees, inverted spectra, non-inverted spectra ...

Comment: `(\forall x) x \cup \emptyset` (everything and nothing)

Comment: @VidMerljak When you are finished, please send one of the shirts to the BBC, they claimed in one of their potcasts, they question latex ability to control an automatic jet fighter...

Comment: @Skillmon: worships in KOMA-Script? I don't think so. There is another package from the same author, but not as part of KOMA-Script.

Comment: I've used LaTeX so send the architect a modified version of his plan of our basement. I've typeset choir music, guitar tabs, songbooks with LaTeX. I've also used LaTeX to create random math exercise sheets to train the calculation skills of primary-school pupils. Nothing as bizarre as drawing a duck, but you can do a lot of things with LaTeX.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I can't find a link to that, but I thought I remembered the description on one of the koma-related sites. Perhaps my memory tricked me and it was only published but not included in KOMA. It is still a use case of LaTeX though.

Comment: [Game of Life](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145319/5763)

Comment: It is also possible to [simulate a Mars rover](https://sdh33b.blogspot.nl/2008/07/icfp-contest-2008.html) using LaTeX (well, technically TeX, but LaTeX is built on top of TeX).

Comment: Making toast? http://tex-talk.net/2012/10/i-tex-therefore-i-toast/

Comment: I've used it to create application Icons. I recall a blog detailing how a sysadmin configured the access to a cruise ships networks (Wifi, Lan the whole shebang) on cruise ships using TeX. He discussed how it neatly output the configuration files and documented the setup which changed whenever new passengers boarded. He never had a follow up saying how he did it but I believe he use dtx files. So I suppose "I never use LaTeX except for system administration". Alternatively if in Ireland "I TeX, ye Kern !".

Answer (score 47):

Create beautiful math exams. My students don't seem to notice

Comment: As someone with professors that use LaTeX, I appreciate it. Nothing worse than an exam that looks like it was made using Word.

Comment: I'm a student and I definitely notice. I have a professor that uses the euro symbol for \in, it is driving me nuts.

Comment: @rotgers: that's awful. There's even a character ∊ Unicode that you can use...

Answer (score 35):

For the purposes of this question I wrote a terminal tic-tac-toe game in LaTeX.

Example run:

```
$ pdflatex tictactoe.tex 
next move X (qwe/asd/zxc)?
\move=q
X..
...
...
next move O (qwe/asd/zxc)?
\move=a
X..
O..
...
next move X (qwe/asd/zxc)?
\move=s
X..
OX.
...
next move O (qwe/asd/zxc)?
\move=z
X..
OX.
O..
next move X (qwe/asd/zxc)?
\move=c
X..
OX.
O.X
X won
Output written on tictactoe.pdf (1 page, 10812 bytes).
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{substr}

% macro for each position
\def\q{.} \def\w{.} \def\e{.}
\def\a{.} \def\s{.} \def\d{.}
\def\z{.} \def\x{.} \def\c{.}
% string separator
\def\P{\newline}
% toggle for finished game
\newif\ifinprogress
\inprogresstrue
\newcommand\checkboard{
    % print board to terminal
    \typeout{\q\w\e}
    \typeout{\a\s\d}
    \typeout{\z\x\c}
    % print board to string, all horizontal, vertical, diagonal lines
    \def\board{\q\w\e\P\a\s\d\P\z\x\c\P\q\a\z\P\w\s\x\P\e\d\c\P\q\s\c\P\e\s\z}
    % horizontal board to print to pdf
    \def\boardprint{\q\w\e\P\a\s\d\P\z\x\c}
    % check for win or tie
    \IfSubStringInString{XXX}{\board}{
        \typeout{X won}
        \inprogressfalse
    }{
        \IfSubStringInString{OOO}{\board}{
            \typeout{O won}
            \inprogressfalse
        }{
            \IfSubStringInString{.}{\board}{}{
                \typeout{Tie}
                \inprogressfalse
            }
        }
    }
}

\newcommand\nextmovex{
    \typein[\move]{next move X (qwe/asd/zxc)?}
    % \def\q{X} etc.
    \expandafter\def\csname\move\endcsname{X}
    % check for win or tie
    \checkboard
    % continue with other player 
    \ifinprogress
        \nextmoveo
    \fi
}
\newcommand\nextmoveo{
    \typein[\move]{next move O (qwe/asd/zxc)?}
    \expandafter\def\csname\move\endcsname{O}
    \checkboard
    \ifinprogress
        \nextmovex
    \fi
}
% start with player X
\nextmovex
\begin{document}
% print final board in pdf
\noindent\texttt{\boardprint}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, there’s the famous [Reversi implementation in TeX](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/reverxii/#reverxii.tex) by Bruno Le Floch, too…

Comment: Made My Day! (which is too short so I write this stuff inside of the brackets)

Answer (score 32):

Here are some of the things I've used LaTeX for:

- Text books. Primary dependencies: [KOMA-Script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) and [`flowfram`](https://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram).
- Novels. Primary dependencies: [`memoir`](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) and [`microtype`](https://ctan.org/pkg/microtype).
- Illustrated children's books. Primary dependencies: [`flowfram`](https://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) and [`extsizes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes).
- Presentations. Primary dependency: [`beamer`](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer).
- Correspondence ([letters](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/correspondence.shtml), [invoices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/invoices.shtml) and quotes). Primary dependency: custom class based on `letter`.
- Business cards. Primary dependency: [`tikz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf).
- [Press releases](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/pressreleases.shtml). Primary dependency: [`pressrelease`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pressrelease).
- Promotional postcards. Primary dependency: [`flowfram`](https://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram).
- [Advance information sheets.](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/flowfram.shtml#aisheet-sample) Primary dependency: [`flowfram`](https://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram).
- Posters. Primary dependency: [`tikz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or [`flowfram`](https://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram).
- Brochures. Primary dependency: [`flowfram`](https://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram).
- Newsletters. Primary dependency: [`flowfram`](https://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram).
- [Limited overs cricket score sheet.](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/packages/crkscrsh/sample.pdf) Primary dependency: custom class based on `article`.
- Poetry (just part of a creative writing course, so no serious use). Primary dependency: `article` and [`verse`](https://ctan.org/pkg/verse) in most cases, but [`shapepar`](https://ctan.org/pkg/verse) in one case with the assistance of [`flowframtk`](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/software/flowframtk/manual/shapepar.shtml) (for a poem about a dripping tap where each verse was shaped like a drop of water).

Comment: Apropos illustrated children's books: The printed version of [„Die Wolke Wolfgang”](https://blacktrash.org/wolkewolfgang/index.html) has been made using LaTeX (with KOMA-Script).

Comment: And of course @NicolaTalbot wrote some of the packages used for the examples in this list expanding the range of possible documents for all of us.

Answer (score 23):

Some more:

- RPG materials: [How do I make my document look like it was written by a Cthulhu-worshipping madman?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29402/28808)
- [Music](http://www.mab.jpn.org/musictex/index_en.html)
- [Pretty pictures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39485/28808) (I have to admit I rather like my own answer there)
- [A poster of an entire thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166418/28808) (also many more conventional posters)
- Also plenty of poetry examples

Answer (score 14):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine,lmodern}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[margin=.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent\sffamily\bfseries
\stackinset{c}{}{t}{190pt}{\parbox{.35\textwidth}{\LARGE\centering I don't always use \LaTeX{},\\
but when I \texttt{\textbackslash do}...\\[20pt]
I always remember to\\ step the counter.}}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{%
  High-Quality-Stretch-Short-sleeved-White-T-Shirt-Men-s-Candy-Colors-Raglan-Blank-T-shirt}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Shirt image obtained from http://g03.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1Aqg4JFXXXXXSXXXXq6xXFXXXy/High-Quality-Stretch-Short-sleeved-White-T-Shirt-Men-s-Candy-Colors-Raglan-Blank-T-shirt.jpg

---

**3-year follow up**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine,lmodern}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[margin=.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent\sffamily\bfseries
\stackinset{c}{}{t}{190pt}{\parbox{.35\textwidth}{\LARGE\centering %
 If you think \LaTeX{}\\
is only good for condoms...\\[20pt]
you ain't lived yet\\\texttt{tex.stackexchange.com}}}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{%
  High-Quality-Stretch-Short-sleeved-White-T-Shirt-Men-s-Candy-Colors-Raglan-Blank-T-shirt}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

A very important type of document: thesis.

Moreover:

- CVs
- greeting cards.

I'm also writing a brief SAS Manual for my newly hired colleagues.

Comment: Not this [SAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Air_Service) I assume, but the programmign language?

Comment: @ChrisH The programming language, of couse: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/381196/101651!

Answer (score 12):

some rather unexpected topics that were the subject of talks at tex conferences ...

at TUG 2015:

- Pavneet Arora on embedded documentation for a flow-leak monitoring system; [video](http://zeeba.tv/fluss-a-flow-leak-monitoring-system/)

at TUG 2016:

- Stefan Kottwitz on "programming Cisco network systems" and "designing converged network solutions" (no published paper or video)
- Matthew Skala on astrological charts; [preprint](http://tug.org/tug2016/preprints/skala.pdf) and [slides](http://tug.org/tug2016/slides/skala.pdf)
- Federico Garcia-De Castro on "TeXcel", a financial tracking and reporting system for keeping the accounts of a non-profit musical organization.  ([paper](http://www.tug.org/members/TUGboat/tb37-2/tb116garcia.pdf) accessible only to TUG members until September 2017)

Answer (score 11):

Solving and generating sudoku puzzles (with the `sudoku bundle`).

Answer (score 11):

I've used LaTeX and some magnets with a sticky face to make a stick-it-on-the-fridge token system to organize the domestic chores for my daughters. It looks like this (French, sorry):[image: domestic chores organizer, in French]

The S and M signs are cut and pasted on the magnets, and then my daughters just place the magnets to pick their chores.

This is made using `tikz` and `Zallman.fd` for the font for S/M.

The full source code is the following:

```
% -*- coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

% \usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[margin=5mm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{arev}

\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\ssz{14mm}

% The commented samples below are good alternatives to Zallman.fd
% \input Acorn.fd
% \renewcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Acorn}{xl}{n}}

% \input AnnSton.fd
% \renewcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{AnnSton}{xl}{n}}

% \input Carrickc.fd
% \renewcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Carrickc}{xl}{n}}

\input Zallman.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Zallman}{xl}{n}}

\newcommand\sqr[1][normal]{%
  \rule{0pt}{13mm}%
  \raisebox{-4mm}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      normal/.style = {black, thick},
      dimmed/.style = {black!30},
      ]
      \draw[#1] (0,0) rectangle (\ssz, \ssz);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}

\newcommand\sqrl[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray] (0,0) rectangle (\ssz, \ssz);
    \node[inner sep=0mm] at (0.5 * \ssz, 0.5 * \ssz) {\scalebox{2.2}{\initfamily #1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\LARGE 
% {\initfamily A}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
    & \bfseries Samedi & \bfseries  Dimanche 
    & \bfseries Lundi & \bfseries Mardi 
    & \bfseries Mercredi & \bfseries Jeudi \\
    Mettre la table midi & \sqr & \sqr & \sqr[dimmed] & & \sqr\\
    Débarrasser midi & \sqr & \sqr & \sqr[dimmed] & & \sqr\\
    Vaisselle midi & \sqr{} \sqr & \sqr{} \sqr & 
    \sqr[dimmed]{} \sqr[dimmed] & & \sqr{} \sqr\\[5mm]
    Mettre la table soir & \sqr & \sqr & \sqr & \sqr & \sqr & \sqr \\
    Débarrasser soir & \sqr & \sqr & \sqr & \sqr & \sqr & \sqr \\
    Vaisselle soir & \sqr{} \sqr & \sqr{} \sqr & \sqr{} \sqr 
                      & % \sqr{} \sqr 
                      & %\sqr{} \sqr 
                      & \sqr{} \sqr \\
    Poubelles &  & \sqr &  &  &  & \sqr \\
    Balai &  & & & \sqr{} \sqr  &  & \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\medskip

\hrule

\medskip
\noindent%
\foreach \n in {1,...,18}{\sqrl{S}\hspace{1mm}}

\medskip
\noindent%
\foreach \n in {1,...,18}{\sqrl{M}\hspace{1mm}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can post the code somewhere, but, still, it's fairly trivial

Comment: @CarLaTeX There you are, have fun !

Answer (score 10):

I find LaTeX to be incredibly useful for computer-generated content. For instance, someone I know has to send out bills to all her clients (she is self-employed). She used to create them in Word, but this involved a lot of work: filling in the addresses, the date, the current rate, etcetera. So I created a simple GUI to manage her clients, which automatically generates her bills using LaTeX. Now she can create her bills with a few clicks of a button: simple and effective!

I'm sure there are many other uses of LaTeX in this direction, though billing seems to be the clearest example.

Comment: I second that. I have to add detailed time tracking records to my invoices. So I export those from the time tracking program to CSV. And with awk I generate Latex, including (long) tables with records, my company letterhead, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Making [MOOCs](https://people.csail.mit.edu/ichuang/edx/latex2edx.php) for the Open edX platform.

Answer (score 7):

Important but not yet mentioned:

- contracts
- legal documents
- all sorts of diagrams
- data plots

Furthermore:

- conference [posters](https://github.com/prestoaghitato/CorpLangPoster) and [programmes](https://github.com/prestoaghitato/CorpLangFlyer)

Also, depending on how 'serious' you wanna be, technically you could use it as a calculator by plotting functions with PGF plots.

Answer (score 6):

To start with, I list the things that came to my mind:

1. Documents in general

   - books
   - scientific articles
   - work reports and logbooks
   - personal files
2. Letters
3. Figures (the `tikz` package is famous for it)
4. Presentations (`beamer`, obviously)
5. T-shirt designs (as in my case - as long as the output is a .pdf file)

Comment: In the document list: thesis. Moreover CVs and greeting cards.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks. You are wellcome to post this as an answer, so people can vote on it.

Comment: You're welcome! Done :):):)

Comment: If your answer started a list it's better to edit it than posting a separate answer.

Comment: @KarlRichter This is well posed remark, but things have already got quite of control. : ) Also, such action would negate the point of voting for answers. Then again, this is the nature of {big-list} tag ...

Comment: Your answer could be made into a wiki-answer and the list adopted. The action to vote an answer is to make clear to people passing by, which answer is helpful and which is not. The effect of gaining reputation is just a nice addition to it.

Answer (score 6):

Creating custom stationery to write on. I created some dot-grid paper with a header to title each page and write my name and a footer where I placed "Page __/__" which I would fill in when I had finished.

It made it easy to find my homework, and make sure I had all of the pages to turn in.

Comment: I did that too.  Such nerds we are.

Answer (score 6):

Besides typesetting documents, TeX is also a Turing-complete language, and can basically do whatever calculations you want (with some extraneous output). Adding the LaTeX macro package to it doesn't change it. The TicTacToe example by Marjin relies on that.

One example, which is used by LaTeX itself (or by packages), is the `docstrip` program – it is a program written in (plain) TeX (but also runs with LaTeX, I think) which converts a "documented TeX archive" (or a set of those) into a package file for easier use (or into the kernel source file).

Comment: TeX is also a **Schmuring-complete** (patent pending) language, meaning "anything that is not possible in a reasonable time/effort will invoke an Turing-completeness argument by its users". Other examples are Brainfuck, iota etc.

Answer (score 6):

At my university, we use LaTeX (among a myriad of other tasks that have already been mentioned) to create exams and worksheets.

- The worksheets use a custom version of [this class](http://archive.cone.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/vorlesung/distributed-systems-s12/ex/uebung.cls) (german)
- I do not know what class is used for the exams. It might be done using a version of [`exam`](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf)

As an anecdote: During winter vacation we teased some of our friends that they would need to learn the numbers of all the ski slopes, as they will be part of the final exam. Presenting them with a fake exam sheet based on the university template really threw them off ;) They all "passed", but none of them got the numbers of the slopes right.

Answer (score 6):

As an archaeologist I do [Harris-Matrixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harris_matrix) with LaTeX as well:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to add that you use LaTeX to design T-shirts!

Answer (score 5):

If you're writing a 300+ page Master's thesis for science or engineering (or any topic really), it's the only way to go. Word starts stalling and taking half a minute to re-compute auto-references past a certain limit every time you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. Tables, `cleverref` references, being able to reference everything (sections, appendices, figures, equations, quotes, chapter numbers, paragraphs even, etc), make it so easy to keep a train of thought.

It's also awesome for writing quizzes and exams, since it's dead easy to just use the `comment` package to prevent the answers from rendering. A little command-line argument magic, and you now have your questions and answer key output documents generated by the same source document, without having to maintain two separate source documents side-by-side. **Even better**, with a little shell scripting knowledge, it's easy to have the questions shuffled, constants in the questions randomized to prevent cheating/collusion, and auto-inserting student/interviewee names into visible (and non-visible) portions of the document.

Finally, it's great for creating "trackable" documents (i.e. embedding copious amounts of watermarking techniques, names, timestamps, hidden meta-data via [**steganography**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography), etc), since you can setup command-line arguments to be set/randomized/etc and passed to `pdflatex` before the "compile" stage.

Answer (score 3):

[LaTeX Hacks](https://oreilly.de/produkt/latex-hacks/) also has a CD cover, an embroidery pattern (Stickvorlage), and a monthly wall calendar.

Comment: I also used LaTeX to print inserts for CD jewelcases.

Answer (score 3):

Well, and do not forget, there was this guy who programmed a mars rover in TeX:
http://sdh33b.blogspot.de/2008/07/icfp-contest-2008.html

(Originally posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104248/what-is-the-most-bizarre-thing-you-have-seen-done-with-tex), however always worth mentioning)

Answer (score 2):

Also research papers! All major publisher provide some template.

Answer (score 2):

Add one:

- Sticky address labels for bulk mailing.

Several years ago I did a bulk mailing for a small nonprofit organization using the LaTeX package `envlab`.  At the time `envlab` formatted everything the way the United States Postal Service required, including the barcode for automated sorting.

Alas, USPS now requires a barcode that includes USPS routing information, so reference to an external database, and `envlab` is not up to this task.  For small bulk mailings, or bulk mailings in a limited geographic area, it should be feasible to hack `envlab` to add the extra routing information by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I had great fun using LaTeX for my wedding invitations, menus, name cards, ceremonial booklets...

Having a macro for the name cards and menus especially was very useful!