# Can a LaTeX formula output its own source code?

Tags: fun, latex-misc, content-replication

There was recently a featured question which about [designing a t-shirt using 
a LaTeX-inspired design](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383292/139447). On that question, there was one comment in particular which caught my attention.

> Perhaps you could put the source for the t-shirt design on the back.
>   <sub>-[wizzwizz4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383292/all-uses-of-latex-i-never-use-latex-except-for#comment948613_383292)</sub>

I initially misinterpreted wizz's comment, thinking that it was referring to a LaTeX formula which would display it's own source code.

Programs that output their own source code, [also known as quines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)), are not uncommon. You can find [quite a few examples](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good) of these over on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). However, across all the quine challenges, I've never seen a LaTeX formula output it's own source code before.

**Are there any examples of a LaTeX formula which draws its own source code?**